# How to change the navigationOption (title) of a DrawerNavigator dynamically?

Tags: javascript, react-native, localization

I have used a library called react-native-localization to translate my app. Everything except titles of the Drawer Navigator and Bottom Tab Navigator will be translated.

Different methods have been tried. But when I was searching for a solution, I came across this saying that navigationOption doesn't re-render the changes and you should return the title value to fix it. Below are some snippets of my code.

```
  changeLangFa() {
        const lan = 'fa';
        saveSettings(lan); 
        RNRestart.Restart();
    }

    changeLangEn() {
        const lan = 'en';
        saveSettings(lan);
        RNRestart.Restart();
    }
```

.....

```
 async componentWillMount() {
        const lan = await loadSettings();
        strings.setLanguage(lan);
    }
```

.....

```
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    AppTabNavigator: {
        screen: AppTabNavigator,
        navigationOptions: ({
            title: strings.settingsPage.settingsTitle,
            drawerIcon: () => (
                <Icon name="cogs" size={22} />
            )
        })
    },
    AboutUs: {
        screen: AboutUs,
        navigationOptions: ({
            title: strings.aboutUsPage.aboutUstitle,
            drawerIcon: () => (
                <Icon name="info-circle" size={23} />
            )
        })
    },
```

First two functions are for saving the desired language and changing it and these to are bind to some buttons. Second part of the code is where the language configuration gets loaded in App.js file. And the last ones are my navigator configurations (Some of it). So am I doing anything wrong? if yes please correct me, if no, would it fix to change navigationOption somehow that will dynamically re-render the changes? if yes, please point out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the answer from hong develop and modifying it, I was able to fix the problem and make a dynamic navigationOptions. The correct code snippet is as below:

**AboutUs.js**

```
static navigationOptions = () => ({
      title: strings.aboutUsPage.aboutUstitle
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Set up in `index.js` and use accordingly.

**index.js**

```js
let strings = new LocalizedStrings({
 en:{
   title:"How do you want your egg today?",
   boiledEgg:"Boiled egg",
   softBoiledEgg:"Soft-boiled egg",
   choice:"How to choose the egg"
 },
 fa: {
   title:"Come vuoi il tuo uovo oggi?",
   boiledEgg:"Uovo sodo",
   softBoiledEgg:"Uovo alla coque",
   choice:"Come scegliere l'uovo"
 }
});

...
componentDidmount() {
 strings.setLanguage('fa'); // When the local value of the user's mobile phone is 'fa'
}
```

**AboutUs.js**

```js
  static navigationOptions = {
    title:{strings.title},
  };

  /* render function, etc */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was useful, but didn't solve the problem. If no one could help, I will mark your answer as the correct one because you kind of answered it.

Comment: By looking again to your answer and making a few changes I was able to solve my problem. The changes were as below,    
    static navigationOptions = () => ({
          title: strings.aboutUsPage.aboutUstitle
        })

Comment: @AliKHalili Yes, if you used the same string.title as my answer, you can't help but solve it. The reason is that you never defined a title. Apply what you define, and you will succeed correctly.

Comment: @AliKHalili If my answer was helpful to you, could you check the V sign and choose my answer?